# KeyError: 'visual' while downloading the subarea from Planet Labs?

Tags: python, planet

I've trying to download an AOI from planet using this same example. [Planet Example Link](https://www.planet.com/docs/guides/quickstart-subarea/)

My code is ditto. I keep getting this error.

> KeyError: 'visual'.

I did activate the scene containing the subarea, number of times.
My code if it helps.

subarea.geojson

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type":"Polygon",
        "coordinates":[
          [
             [
                -114.176423930378903,
                32.691933554346988
             ],
             [
                -114.176423930378903,
                32.685249521402788
             ],
             [
                -114.168019741897595,
                32.685249521402788
             ],
             [
                -114.168019741897595,
                32.691933554346988
             ],
             [
                -114.176423930378903,
                32.691933554346988
             ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

download_aoi.py

```
    from osgeo import gdal
    from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
    import os
    import requests

    PLANET_API_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxx'
    item_id = "20161109_173041_0e0e"
    item_type = "PSScene3Band"
    asset_type = "visual"
    item_url = 'https://api.planet.com/data/v1/item-types/{}/items/{}/assets'.format(item_type, item_id)

    # Request a new download URL
    result = requests.get(item_url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(PLANET_API_KEY, ''))
    download_url = result.json()[asset_type]['location']


    vsicurl_url = '/vsicurl/' + download_url
    output_file = item_id + '_subarea.tif'

    # GDAL Warp crops the image by our AOI, and saves it
    gdal.Warp(output_file, vsicurl_url, dstSRS = 'EPSG:4326', cutlineDSName = 'subarea.geojson', cropToCutline = True)
```

Error:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "download_aoi.py", line 14, in 
**download_url = result.json()[asset_type]['location']**
**KeyError: 'visual'**

Comment: The result seems to have no "visual" key. Whats the output of `print(result.text)`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Outputs:   {} , completely blank. I can't understand the reason. Is the item_id in planet example wrong!

Comment: Maybe it's best to ask planet: `If you have any trouble with this guide, let us know at support@planet.com.`

Comment: Hey, I used a  different set of inputs, the output of `result.text` does contain location, and I get key error 'location'. result.text output here. https://docs.google.com/document/d/109h_GRod7iMoodQ4pTYkS-6bi0y059rubIKiNlMAzO0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: please edit the question with the new information and also add the new output.

Comment: Since its a different one, I'll ask another question, please do answer if possible.